# PID fails too hot temperature with new hotend on Tevo Tornado

Tags: hotend, electronics, heat

I am new to 3D printing. I had a big issue with the full hotend: thermocouple broke, the fan broke, plastic everywhere... (I don't really know why as hundreds of prints were good before)

Anyway, I decided to replace the full hotend (2 fans + thermocouple + cartridge). I have the issue of nozzle temp. rising to max value very fast (250 °C defined as max temp. to not exceed in my printer setup). PID autotune failed because of this.

I checked my printer, it is a 24 V supply (Tevo Tornado)! When I measure the resistance of the old cartridge, it is 40 Ohms and the new one is 4 Ohms. I would like to replace it but really don't know how to do with the 8-pin connector...

I don't know if the new hot end is for 12 V or for 24 V power supply but I thought it was not a problem anyway with my 24 V supply... I am completely lost here...

Could you help me with this issue?

Comment: See e.g. [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/13310/)

Answer (score 2):

A heater cartridge with a resistance of 4 Ohms (including the cables) is designed for use with a 12 Volt system. When installed on a 12 Volt system, it will have a power output of around 40 Watts. This will increase to 160 Watts if it is installed on a 24 Volt system.

Comment: This means I can burn my system, right ?
Is there any possibility to adapt this one ? I thought to use a 12 V on a 24 V was possible, but not the opposite.

Comment: @saphozzo Yes. That power level is dangerous. Use a 24V heater cartridge.